# Understanding the Open method and the Try block in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

I'm using VB.NET for the first time, to check if a file is in use, but there are some lines of code that I don't fully understand.

Can someone explain the two lines of code highlighted below in the comments?

```
Public Sub Main()
    IsFileInUse("C:\someFolder\file.pdf")
End Sub


Function IsFileInUse(filePath As String) As Boolean
    IsFileInUse = False
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filePath) Then
        Dim fileInfo As System.IO.FileInfo
        Dim stream As System.IO.FileStream
        fileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(filePath)
        Try
            ' Can someone explain this line of code?
            ' how does this determines where to go from here, Catch or Finally?
            stream = fileInfo.Open(System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite, System.IO.FileShare.None)
        Catch
            IsFileInUse = True
            MessageBox.Show("It looks like the file is opened")
        Finally
            If stream IsNot Nothing Then
                ' What is this closing?
                stream.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    Else 
        MessageBox.Show("File does NOT Exist")
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does this determines where to go from here, Catch or Finally?

Look at the [documentation for FileInfo.Open](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya63c7c5(v=vs.110).aspx). The Exceptions section shows all of the possible exceptions that can happen.

If an exception is thrown, the Catch block will be executed.

The Finally block always gets executed, whether or not an exception was thrown.

> What is this closing?

It will release the stream's resources, in this case it will close the file.

Comment: Is there way to print out the Exception message? I tried casting as follow...  `MessageShow(ToString(stream))` but of course it doesn't work. I'm just curious to see the output.

Comment: I'm having a hard time reading the VB.NET documentation. I'm used to see something like where they show the parameters a method takes, something like...`FileInfo.Open(AsString, As String, As String) ` than explain what each parameter does.

Comment: to show the exception, change `Catch` to `Catch ex As Exception`, then inside the Catch block you can access the exception message as `ex.Message` and display it in a message box or write to the console (or however you want to display it). Generally speaking, you don't want to just use `Exception` and instead catch an exception that will actually be thrown (such as `FileNotFoundException` or `IOException`), and utilizing multiple Catch blocks, as described in the link provided in Steven Doggart's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Try block runs the code. In the Try block, a stream is used to open the file and access its contents. If that code errors for any reason, it will throw an Exception, which will then cause to the Catch block to be run. The Finally block of the code will run whether an Exception is thrown or not. In the Finally block, the stream to the File is being closed.

Answer (score 1):

The code is determining whether or not the file is currently "in use" by any other processes by attempting to open the file with read/write access.  Whether the opening of the file fails or not, it always closes the file stream.  It assumes that if opening the file in that mode fails for any reason, then it must be because it is "in use".  That's a bad assumption to make, and likely not the best way to accomplish it anyway, but for what it's worth, that's what it's doing.

The `Try`/`Catch` block is VB.NET's preferred syntax for exception handling (it replaces the older `On Error` syntax which predated .NET).  When anything inside of the `Try` section throws an exception, execution will jump to the `Catch` section.  Once execution of the `Catch` section completes, it then jumps to the `Finally` section.  If nothing in the `Try` section throws an exception, then once it's done, it also jumps to the `Finally` section.  Essentially, everything in the Finally section is "guaranteed" to execute, whether or not an exception occurred, whereas the code in the `Catch` section only executes when there is an exception.

In other words, consider this example:

```
' Outputs "ABCE" (does not output "D")
Console.Write("A")
Try
    Console.Write("B")
    Console.Write("C")
Catch
    Console.Write("D")
Finally
Console.Write("E")
```

And compare it to this example:

```
' Outputs "ABDE" (does not output "C")
Console.Write("A")
Try
    Console.Write("B")
    Throw New Exception()
    Console.Write("C")
Catch
    Console.Write("D")
Finally
Console.Write("E")
```

See [the MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx) for much more information on the topic.